# Using CSS To Create a Fixed, Content-Overlapping Footer

Tags: css, footer

I'm completly new with CSS coding and hope someone can help me. I'm want my images to display BEHIND the footer when you scroll down on the page on mobile version, how do I do this? [This](https://www.fortlaan93.com/home) is how it's looking now.

Here is the CSS code for my footer:

```
.Footer{

width:100%;

position:fixed;

top:auto;

bottom:0px;

background-color:rgba(242,231,213,2); }
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `z-index: 0 !important;` to your `.sqs-gallery-design-stacked-slide` class as it set `z-index` value from carousel adds bigger one. So adding below css will solve the issue.

```
.sqs-gallery-design-stacked-slide{
  z-index: 0 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply add a high `z-index` value to make the footer always on the top of all content :

```
.Footer {
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: auto;
  bottom: 0px;
  z-index: 999;
  background-color: rgba(242, 231, 213, 2);
}
```

As you can see in this screenshot :

[image]

Your slides are having a big z-index value that make them go over the footer. So the z-index of the footer need to be bigger.

Comment: your have to set a hight z-index cause your slider add a z-index of 898 on your images (no clues..)